# Call method after UILocalNotification fired in iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications

In my app , I want to call a method when a Local notification fired, How can I call method ?

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method , I did this,

```
 NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
 NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
[components setHour:4];
[components setMinute:5];
   NSDate *next9am = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

  UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
  notification.fireDate = next9am;
  notification.alertBody = @"It's been 24 hours.";
// Set a repeat interval to daily
notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

just set a LocalNotification.

Answer (score 0):

You respond to local notifications in 2 ways:

1. `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` - If the app is closed (terminated) and then opened through the notification.
2. `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` - If the app is open/inactive.

Comment: My app is in background lets say becuase I want that notification will fire daily at 12 am so when notification is fired I want to call another method

Comment: You can't call a method when the notification is fired, only once the user interacts with it. Alternatively you can use background tasks to check if your notification has/should have been called and do something in that instance.